# Código jquery no funciona en Safari y sí en Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

el código del ejemplo no funciona en Safari pero sí lo hace en Google Chrome, puede que no sea compatible con éste navegador? O el problema es de mi versión de Safari?
Debería ser que cuando se introduce el puntero dentro del Cuadrado Rojo se activa la secuencia de funciones descrita en el javascript en el tiempo elegido y sin embargo tarda 20 veces más en safari.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.position').css({
            '-webkit-text-stroke-width': '5px',
            '-webkit-text-stroke-color': 'rgba(0,170,209,0.20)'
          })
        },
        1500);
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.position').css({
            '-webkit-text-stroke-width': '15px',
            '-webkit-text-stroke-color': 'rgba(0,170,209,0.10)'
          })
        },
        1000);
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.position').css({
            '-webkit-text-stroke-width': '30px',
            '-webkit-text-stroke-color': 'rgba(0,170,209,0.10)'
          })
        },
        500);
    },
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4px;
  color: rgba(0, 170, 209, 1.00);
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(228, 0, 253, 1.00);
}
.position2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#wraperito {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger" style="width:100px;height:100px; border:red solid 1px; float:left; position:fixed; margin-top:0px;"></div>
<div id="wraperito">
  <pre class="position">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^llccd----A^A^^^YAAY^AA^^AAYd,;cd^^^ll'..   .;l-AAAdc^l;:^^dAd^ddll^l;:l,    .... ...   .......,...'::'  ..'...   .,:::ldAAAAAAAAA^YY^AYY^-
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ddd^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^d^^^^^ddd^^^^llll^----d-^YYYAAAYY^AAA-^-^-l::cc:lc...   ':^-AAAAdd^cc^^^^^d--ll^cc^l'   ...   ...  ...........',,.   .....    
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Tampoco en Firefox 45. Deberias revisar la doc referente al uso de `-webkit-text-stroke-width` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-width

Comment: Gracias @jasilva buscaré ahí la solución mientras espero alguna respuesta!

Comment: `-webkit-` nunca funcionara en mozilla, es el prefijo del motor que usan chrome y safari,.

Comment: Ok @rnd entonces sí que no entiendo por qué en safari va tan mal

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @IvanSoler ¿qué versión de Safari usas?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Versión 7.0.6 (9537.78.2)

Comment: @IvanSoler puedes poner el error que te indica el navegador ?

Comment: @Santi92 cómo veo eso?

Comment: @IvanSoler Activa las opciones de desarrollo como se indica en este link http://es.ccm.net/faq/5735-safari-mostrar-el-menu-desarrollo-en-la-barra-de-menus saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es la función setTimeout, que por alguna razón falla en Safari, tanto mobile como en desktop.

Te recomiendo utilizar .bind, te queraría algo así

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $('.position').css({
            '-webkit-text-stroke-width': '5px',
            '-webkit-text-stroke-color': 'rgba(0,170,209,0.20)'
          })
}.bind(this),1500);
```

Por otro lado, `-webkit` no funciona en firefox, para eso debes usar `-moz` , te recomiendo usar la página http://caniuse.com/#search=webkit para ver que funcionalidades se pueden usar en qué navegadores!
Saludos!